# Open source path file from activecell VBA

Tags: vba, excel

"This code can open source file with any path .. but now I have the list of source path files on sheet1 and I want to open the file on active cell.. How should I fix this code ? "

```
Dim Ret

Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files (*), *")

Sheet2.Activate

If Ret <> False Then
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))

    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value of the *ActiveCell* to `Ret`.

```
Ret = ActiveCell.Value
```

Then check if the returned path is valid. Something like:

```
If Dir(Ret) <> "" Then
    '~~> rest of your code here
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid Path"
    '~~> or do something else
End If
```

HTH.